# Can/should type_traits help in accessing an arbitrary structure as a spatial array?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

Say I have a class that has spatial members (x, y, z) or (lat, lon) but also other attributes as members.  I'd like to use an array of these to create a searchable KD-Tree.

As a start, I'm able to `std::array<Node, N>`, `std::vector<Node>` or `Node[5]` with the following:

```
template <typename SPATIAL_CONTAINER,
          int NUM_DIMENSIONS>
struct Array_traits
{
    /* Dimension handling */
    static constexpr int DIM = NUM_DIMENSIONS;
    static_assert(DIM > 1, "KD-Trees require DIM of at least 2.");

    /* Spatial container handling */
    using Array = SPATIAL_CONTAINER;
    // Get the type used for each spatial element.  Decay<> removes any const/Ref
    typedef typename std::decay<decltype(*std::begin(Array()))>::type Node;
}
```

Where I'm struggling is how (or if) I should create a traits template for Node that provides access to the specific spatial members.

```
// Doesn't work, just thoughts on the intended interface
template <int NUM_DIMENSIONS>
struct Node_traits
{
    /* Dimension handling */
    static constexpr int DIM = NUM_DIMENSIONS;
    static_assert(DIM > 1, "KD-Trees require DIM of at least 2.");

    CoordType get<0> { return x; } // or { return lat; }
    CoordType get<1> { return y; } // or { return lon; }
    constexpr if (DIM >= 2) {
        CoordType get<2>() { return z; }
    }
}
```

Is this a reasonable path forward, and if so are there hints on how to create a wrapper/traits to provide a specific interface on a specific type?

Comment: `constexpr if (DIM >= 2)` cannot be used at that scope, `requires (DIM >= 2)` can though (c++20).

Comment: Should it be `template <typename Node> struct Node_traits` that you can specialize for your classes `Vec3` (x, y, z), `Coord` (lat, lon)?

Comment: @Jarod42 - Is there a C++17 way of enforcing method count based on NUM_DIMENSIONS?  And yes, `typename Node` should have been included, apologies I just wrote that quickly to try to show my line of thinking

Comment: `template <std::size_t I> CoordType get() const {static_assert(I < DIM); if constexpr(I == 0) return x; else if constexpr (I == 1) return y; else if constexpr (I == 2) return z;}`?